# How can I pick more than one point using matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have written the code to plot, pick, drag and get the final coordinates using matplotlib. But once I pick the first point I can't pick except for the first one.
How can I pick other points also and get the new location(coordinates) for all?

Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as lines
from matplotlib.collections import PathCollection

lines.VertexSelector

class draggable_lines:
    def __init__(self, ax):
        self.ax = ax
        self.c = ax.get_figure().canvas

        self.line = lines.Line2D(x, y, picker=5, marker='o', markerfacecolor='r', color='w')
        self.ax.add_line(self.line)
        self.c.draw_idle()
        self.sid = self.c.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.clickonline)

    def clickonline(self, event):
        if event.artist:
            print("line selected ", event.artist)
            self.follower = self.c.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", self.followmouse)
            self.releaser = self.c.mpl_connect("button_press_event", self.releaseonclick)

    def followmouse(self, event):
        self.line.set_data([event.xdata, event.ydata])
        self.c.draw_idle()

    def releaseonclick(self, event):
        data = self.line.get_data()
        print(data)

        self.c.mpl_disconnect(self.releaser)
        self.c.mpl_disconnect(self.follower)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x, y = [2,4,5,7], [8, 6, 12,9]
ax.plot(x, y)
Vline = draggable_lines(ax)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current problem is, that you set your entire `x` and `y` data to only one `x, y` datapoint.

You need to make note of the *index* of the event you picked in your method `clickonline` and then modify only the data at that index during your `followmouse` method.
Also, I don't know if it is on purpose, but you might want to change your event for the `releasonclick` method to a `"button_release_event"`.

Here's the complete code which should work as expected:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as lines

class draggable_lines:
    def __init__(self, ax):
        self.ax = ax
        self.c = ax.get_figure().canvas

        self.line = lines.Line2D(x, y, picker=5, marker='o', markerfacecolor='r', color='b')
        self.ax.add_line(self.line)
        self.c.draw_idle()
        self.sid = self.c.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.clickonline)

    def clickonline(self, event):
        if event.artist:
            print("line selected ", event.artist)
            self.currentIdx = event.ind
            self.follower = self.c.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", self.followmouse)
            self.releaser = self.c.mpl_connect("button_release_event", self.releaseonclick)

    def followmouse(self, event):
        if self.currentIdx.size != 0:
            if event.xdata and event.ydata:
                d = list(self.line.get_data())
                d[0][int(self.currentIdx)] = event.xdata
                d[1][int(self.currentIdx)] = event.ydata
                self.line.set_data(d)
                self.c.draw_idle()

    def releaseonclick(self, event):
        data = self.line.get_data()
        print(data)
        self.c.mpl_disconnect(self.releaser)
        self.c.mpl_disconnect(self.follower)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x, y = [2,4,5,7], [8, 6, 12,9]
ax.plot(x, y, color='w')
Vline = draggable_lines(ax)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The code is working fine. And also thanks for correcting me in 'button_press_event' and 'button_release_event'.